# Working with checkbox array values and dumping into MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

From a checkbox submit(post) i have an array like this. So this value will be dynamic in form submit. The variable name is $my_values.

## Output

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 2_6
        [3] => 3
        [4] => 3_7
        [5] => 3_8
        [6] => 4
        [7] => 4_9
        [8] => 4_10
        [9] => 4_11
        [10] => 4_12
        [11] => 4_13
        [12] => 4_13_14
        [13] => 5
    )
```

## Expected Output

```
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14
```

So I need to get the output as above in a single variable. How can I achieve that?

In other words :

**$my_values is having the array as i have mentioned. i want one more variable $my_results which will convert the array values and give it as a single value with comma seperator (i.e 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14)**

Thanks
Kimz

Comment: What does "4_13_14" mean?

Comment: `array_keys($array)` ?

Comment: that is mainmenu_submenu_subsub_menu

Comment: @hindmost - could u give me a codesnippet. sorry my bad memory

Comment: @user3350885 That was exactly a code snippet

Comment: @hindmost - I think he needs values, not array_keys. He doesn't have 0 in expected output

Comment: no. that array_keys($array) dnt work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need each id just once, you can do something like this:

```
$tmp = implode(',', $my_values);
$tmp = str_replace('_', ',', $tmp);
$idList = explode(',', $tmp);
$my_results = implode(',', array_unique($idList));
echo $my_results;
```

Comment: no bro, this dnt help me. i was expecting an output in comma seperator but the array value is what i have mentioned earlier. could you give one more try and help me.

Comment: well I am not sure if I understand what you need

Comment: see, $my_values is having the array as i have mentioned. i want one more variable $my_results which will convert the array values and give it as a single value with comma seperator (i.e 1,2,3,4,5 etc..)

Comment: sorry for confusing you.  your code works perfect for me.. thanks again

Comment: sorry, i don't have enough reputation.